# Proof of connection between two complex set

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

This is an example in my undergraduate complex analysis textbook

Let $S$ be the open set consisting of all points $z$ such that $|z|<1$ or $|z-2|<1$. State why $S$ is not connected.

Intuitively, I would assume that since the only common point in the closure of $|z|<1$ and $|z-2|<1$ is $z=1$, since $z=1$ is not in the set of $|z|<1$ and $|z-2|<1$, then the sets are not connected, and this is how the book explains it. However, I didn't feel that it was rigorous, what is another way I can prove this?

Any hint would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sets $\{z \in \mathbb C : |z| < 1\}$ and $\{z \in \mathbb C : |z - 2| < 1\}$ are open balls centered at $0$ and $2$ respectively. These sets are disjoint, for suppose $z_0$ were in both sets, then we would have the following contradiction:
$$
2 = |z_0 - (z_0 - 2)| \le |z_0| + |z_0 - 2| < 2
$$

Thus, the set in question is the union of two open, disjoint sets. It follows that it's disconnected.

Comment: Thanks but how does continuity relates to openess of a set?

Comment: @user1433153 Let $f(z) = |z|$. $\{z \in \mathbb C : |z| < 1\} = f^{-1}((-\infty, 1))$. And we know that $(-\infty, 1)$ is open and the continuous preimage of an open set is open.

Comment: It is worth noting that using continuity to show openness is an overkill for these particular sets, as they are open balls. Use whichever method you prefer!

Answer (score 1):

For open sets in $\mathbb{C}$ (or $\mathbb{R}^n$ for that matter) connected and path-connected are the same. Any path connecting $z = 0$ with $z=2$ would have to intersect $\operatorname{Re} z = 1$ (by the intermediate value theorem), but your $S$ contains no point on that line.